# Как написать бекэнд приложение на laravel а фронд на dart(flutter)?

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart

Было бы интересно , если написать часть бекэнд на ларавеле , а фронт на язык dart(flutter). Если у кого то есть опыт , пожалуйста поделитесь, или какими нибудь источниками и видеоуроками. Спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Можешь написать REST API на laravel, а на flutter использовать данные полученные через API